# winforms MDI how to make a child form look like a natural part of the parent

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, mdi

The problem is this - I have a main form (`parent`) with a menu and several other forms which are children I want them to load in the main form. The problem that I met is - the `child` form is loaded within the main form(`parent`) but it looks like a separate window. This:

[image]

And it not only stays like window within a window but also don't get resized when the `parent` is which seems logical but is not what I want.

What I want is something like this :

[image]

I want the `child` forms to be loaded without the window controllers for `minimize`, `maximize`, `close`, the blue line and all that stuff but instead to look like a part of the `parent` window and respond to some parent events like `resize`.

Comment: Then why would you need MDI at all?

Comment: Because: I'm still learning but still It's part of my work. I work on inherited project and there it's made with MDI. I post another question earlier for how to do it and I was guided to using MDI.. These are the reasons I can think of right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following code into your children windows (and subscribe on FormLoaded event)

```
private void FormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```